viteでreactを構築してもnpm run dev でプレビューを表示してもなにも表示されない
プログラミング歴数が月の初心者です。code-serverを利用しています。
npm create vite→reactを選択→javasprict+swcを選択し、その後は指示通りにやったのですが、npm run devでプレビューを表示してもなにも表示されない(白紙)です。以下はデベロッパーツールのエラーの写真です。
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
main.jsx:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
@react-refresh:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
:8080/vite.svg:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

アンインストールなどもしましたが、直りません。node.jsはインストール済みです。
原因はなんなのですか?
ご教示お願いします。
